# Spring Boot PropertiesLauncher, MANIFEST Main Class Cannot resolve class

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin-flow

Attempting to setup Spring Boot to load an external jar, in this case a Vaadin view, but will need ability to add external jars in other cases.
The idea being to bring the view into the Vaadin application at an application restart.
In Intellij, I have set an application runtime option
`-Dloader.path=/home/paulf/vaadin/repository/extjars`
and in the pom

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5895</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
```

All seems to compile OK but the Main-Class in the manifest shows red and reports
`Cannot resolve class 'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher'`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 21
Implementation-Title: Quick N Easy
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
Start-Class: com.qnenet.qne.QNEApplication
Spring-Boot-Version: 3.0.5
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

I have tried Spring Boot 3.0.5 and 3.2.2 with same problem in both understanding that in those 2 versions the actual PropertiesLauncher package has changed.

It seems that there is not much demand for using loader.path as all the tutorials and videos concentrate more on external properties.

Any assistance in sorting this out, much appreciated.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.qnenet</groupId>
    <artifactId>qne</artifactId>
    <name>Quick N Easy</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.1.3</vaadin.version>
        <selenium.version>4.8.1</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.73.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ez-vcard</groupId>
            <artifactId>ez-vcard</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.rctcwyvrn</groupId>
            <artifactId>blake3</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.hl7.fhir.r4</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.hl7.fhir.r5</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.auties00</groupId>
            <artifactId>noise-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.tomsdevsn</groupId>
            <artifactId>hetznercloud-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5895</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        --enable-preview
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: You did try the relocated one `org.springframework.boot.loader.launch. PropertiesLauncher`? I do assume you haven't written the manifest yourself but let that be fully automated?

Comment: Correct, I have tried both the system as required for 3.0.5 and 3.2.2. The manifests are auto created as a result of the ZIP layout in the pom. In both  cases the Main-Class entry is not resolved in both the old an new packages.

Comment: There must then be something in your pom that modifies the manifest. Please provide your full pom and not snippets.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your interest, full pom added.

Comment: I don't see conflicting versions, maybe this is an oversight in the ZIP layout or maybe that the Vaadin plugin does an overwrite somewhere?